# Removing javax/rmi/CORBA corba jars from Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, linkageerror

QDeploying a service on JBOSS EAP 6.4 fetches an linking error while calling and ejb hosted on Jboss.I want to override the orb implementation but get the linkage error
Can someone help me with the steps to exclude this jboss rmi jar.
I tried excluding it in jboss deployment structure but in vain.

```
loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method 
"com.ibm.rmi.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(Lorg/omg/CORBA/portable/InputStream;ILjava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/omg/SendingContext/RunTime;)Ljava/io/Serializable;" 
the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the    current class, com/ibm/rmi/io/ValueHandlerImpl, 
and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for    interface
 javax/rmi/CORBA/ValueHandler have different Class objects for the type    java/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/omg/SendingContext/RunTime;)
 Ljava/io/Serializable; used in the signature
```

Comment: How did you get the IBM implementation in there? Remove it.

Comment: NB Your problem doesn't have anything to do with '`javax.rmi.CORBA` jars', which don't exist. This package is in the JDK.